# UDP checksum fail for tunneled packet

Tags: udp, wireshark, checksum

I am generating GTP tunneled packets, the format is as follows:

"Outter IP" -> "Outter UDP" -> "GTP" -> "Inner IP" -> "Inner UDP"

The UDP check sum algorithm I'm using is actually from DHCPd

```
**********************code snippet start **********************
udp_header->check = wrapsum(in_cksum((unsigned char *)udp_header, sizeof(struct udp_header),
                                       in_cksum((unsigned char *)&buffer[i], send_len-i,
                        in_cksum((unsigned char *)&ip_header->saddr,
                             2*sizeof(ip_header->saddr),
                             IPPROTO_UDP + ntohs(udp_header->len)))));

/* ******************************************* */

/*
 * Checksum routine for Internet Protocol family headers (C Version)
 *
 * Borrowed from DHCPd
 */

static u_int32_t in_cksum(unsigned char *buf,
              unsigned nbytes, u_int32_t sum) {
  uint i;

  /* Checksum all the pairs of bytes first... */
  for (i = 0; i < (nbytes & ~1U); i += 2) {
    sum += (u_int16_t) ntohs(*((u_int16_t *)(buf + i)));
    /* Add carry. */
    if(sum > 0xFFFF)
      sum -= 0xFFFF;
  }

  /* If there's a single byte left over, checksum it, too.   Network
     byte order is big-endian, so the remaining byte is the high byte. */
  if(i < nbytes) {
#ifdef DEBUG_CHECKSUM_VERBOSE
    debug ("sum = %x", sum);
#endif
    sum += buf [i] << 8;
    /* Add carry. */
    if(sum > 0xFFFF)
      sum -= 0xFFFF;
  }

  return sum;
}

/* ******************************************* */

static u_int32_t wrapsum (u_int32_t sum) {
  sum = ~sum & 0xFFFF;
  return htons(sum);
}


**********************code snippet end**********************
```

Both outter UDP and inner UDP calls uses the same check sum function. However, my inner UDP is fine but my outter UDP is failing wireshark's check sum check. Does anyone have any recommendations on this issue?